# how to include main domain and several subdomains with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I am trying to build a regex that looks very similar to this,
as for an example,

`https://[a-zA-Z].google.com`which applied to the main domain.
I was wondering how do I make it work with including the main domain which is the google.com part?

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend you to read some basics on the regex topic and try out some builders, they are very helpful (my fav https://regex101.com/)

So in your case, first of all let's fix the original regex

1. Escape special characters
   `https:\/\/[a-zA-Z]\.google\.com`
2. `[a-zA-Z]` group will match only a single symbol, so you need to add `+` if you want there to be at least one character in the group or `*` for any amount of characters (including 0)
   `https:\/\/[a-zA-Z]*\.google\.com`
3. Domain name may contain a dash `-` and numbers (sometimes even non-ascii characters, but let's not dig into it just yet)
   `https:\/\/[a-zA-Z-0-9]*\.google\.com`

Now we're almost there.
You can add `?` after a symbol in regex to make it optional

`https:\/\/[a-zA-Z-0-9]*\.?google\.com` will be your final regex

I hope that's clear. Don't hesitate to ask any questions :)

Comment: hi Alexey, yes i will read have a read through it today, thank you so much for your help!